# Measure Of Dispersion - Coefficient of variation

Tags: self-study, dispersion

The sum of squares of deviations of 15 observations from their mean 20 is 240, then what is the value of coefficient of variation (C.V.)? please show the process.

Comment: If it is a 'self-study' then please add 'self study' tag and let us know what you have tried to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

The CV is a scale invariant measure of variability, which the standard deviation is not. This means that the volatility of information with completely differing means and SDs can be made comparable. It is calculated as the Std Dev / Mean * 100. The formula simply standardizes the SD to the level of the data.

A good example are stock prices: consider two stocks, stock 1 has a mean of 500 and a SD of 100 while stock 2 has a mean of 50 and a SD of 20. You can't look at the SDs and determine which stock has more volatility since they are at such widely differing levels or scale. You can, however, estimate the CVs, e.g., for stock 1 this is 100 / 500 *100 = 20, while for stock 2 it is 40. Therefore, stock 2 has more inherent volatility than stock 1.